# How to change the language of a wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change english placeholders from the Davinci2 wordpress theme. But I'm not able to find how to do this. If I check the 'Theme editor' I can see that labels are being translated in the PHP code:

```
 <?php _e( 'View cart', 'dav2' ) ?>
```

Where can I edit these labels? Or do I have to change these texts manually in every PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly change your language of WP installation.This is finished by go to **Settings → General**. Set the Site Language option and save the settings

Next,find the languages folder of the theme: `wp-content/themes/<theme-slug>/languages/`

There find a file `<theme-slug>.pot`. Load this file(catalog) in the PoEdit and start translating.When completed,save the .po file in the folder `wp-content/languages/themes/` and name it regarding your locale. For eg: For French language name it as `template-theme-Fr.po` ,corresponding `.mo` file will be automatically created next to the `.po` file

NOTE: It is not recommended for saving translation files in the the directory anymore, but in the `wp-content/languages/themes` instead. This way translations are kept when you update the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Use this app https://poedit.net/download to read .po in your themes . Folow instruction and you can translate themes